# Passing the selected value from one drop down to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a drop down that reads in drives from my local machine. There is another DDL that I would like to link to the drive DDL. So whichever value is selected, I would like to pass that to the second DDL to display directories on that drive, although I am running into some troubles. A newline constant keeps popping up. Any ideas? Thanks

```
    //get value from first Drive drop down
    var driveValue = ddl_listDrives.SelectedValue.ToString();

    //pass it in directories to be called when btn is clicked
    var directorys = Directory.GetDirectories("@" + driveValue + ":\");
```

Comment: `"@" + driveValue + ":\"` looks wrong... are you sure it shouldn't be `driveValue + @":\"`?

Comment: when I hard it, it takes it as GetDirectory(@"C:\); So I figured a string could be built to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following line is incorrect, because the `":\"` implies that another character will be provided after the `\` to form a control character...

```
var directorys = Directory.GetDirectories("@" + driveValue + ":\");
```

In order to have `"c:\dir\file.txt"` in C# you either need `"c:\\dir\\file.txt"` or (as you have mentioned in your comment) `@"c:\dir\file.txt"` which is called a "quoted string literal" ([see here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

What I believe you should have is **ONE** of the following lines...

```
var directorys = Directory.GetDirectories(driveValue + @":\");
var directorys = Directory.GetDirectories(driveValue + ":\\");
```

Comment: Both return that the given path is not supported.

Comment: @jpavlov, have you checked that the value(s) returned by `ddl_listDrives` correctly fits into that format? In other words, are you sure it's just returning "C" or "D" for instance?

Comment: Thanks. I was actually already returning the :\ part. Good analysis!